# Chromium URL Slashes

Tags: chromium, slash

I'm trying to connect my company's web page. I noticed a problem and couldn't figure it out.

When I type "http://www.example.com/a" it's redirecting to 404 page. But when I type /a/ instead of /a, page is loading without any problems.

This issue is only for Chromium, Firefox renders both /a and /a/ as same URL's and page is loading without any problems.

Can anyone explain me why I'm having this issue? Or is there any bug reports about this?

My system is: Ubuntu 12.10.1 LTS - 32bit OS and Chromium 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 (144678) browser.

Thanks in advance.